# How to restrict class-scoped type parameter to primitive wrappers (numbers) and String?

Tags: java, generics

how can I restrict , in a generic class, to be a primitive wrapper type (Integer, Long, etc..) or a String? Something like this (pseudocode):

```
public class GroupNotificationService<String OR T extends Number>
```

Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to restrict a *Generic* in the first place?

Comment: @user1438038: That's the whole point of bounds.

Comment: Sure, but the primitive wrappers and ``String`` have no mutual parent class (except for ``Object``). And you cannot extend multiple classes in bounds. The only such thing you can do, is ``class MyClass<T extends A & B & C>`` where ``A`` is a class and ``B`` and ``C`` are interfaces.

Comment: @user1438038: Ok, so I guess you're asking the OP "In what situation would an OR bound actually be useful?" (as opposed to the kinds of bounds that Java already does provide).

Comment: Yes, I was rather questioning the OP's general intention for the restriction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that with type parameters; if they do allow to have multiple bounds (as in `T extends A & B` etc), they are additive only.

However you can do that using a static factory method to generate your class:

```
public static <T> GroupNotificationService<T> forClass(final Class<T> c)
{
    // check that c is correct, then
    return new GroupNotificationService<T>(whatever);
}
```